# How to configure hazelcast IMDG for readiness probe

Tags: java, spring-boot, hazelcast, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying implement readiness probe using actuator in springboot. I already have database health check using readiness probe in my helm:

```
-  name: management.endpoint.health.group.readiness.include
   value: 'readinessState,db'
```

I am guessing that I just need to moditfy value portion to add Hazelcast IMDG, but I am not sure if this is the case. I couldn't find good website that explains how to configure it. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

[HazelcastHealthIndicator](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/hazelcast/HazelcastHealthIndicator.java) is automatically configured as described in [Spring Boot Actuator: Production-ready Features](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html). However, from what I see, it only checks if Hazelcast exists and has UUID.

If you want some more Hazelcast specific readiness health check (like checking `hazelcast/health/ready` endpoint or `hazelcast/health/cluster-safe`), then I guess that you need to write a [custom Spring Actuator Health Check Indicator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#writing-custom-healthindicators).